# Using NSDecimalNumber in for Loop?

Tags: objective-c, math, for-loop, nsdecimalnumber

I have a loop i am trying to run with NSDecimalNumber values but the value returned is always the same. I understand NSDecimalNumber isn't mutable but i originally used double values and was getting the wrong result at the end which I assume is some floating point error/rounding error. Here is the code:

```
double balanceAmount = loanAmountValue;
        double rtemp = r / (n * 12);
        double intA = balanceAmount * rtemp;
        double principalA = payfinal - intA;
        double principal = balanceAmount - principalA;
        NSDecimalNumber *balDeciminal = (NSDecimalNumber *) [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:balanceAmount];
        NSDecimalNumber *rTempDecimal = (NSDecimalNumber *) [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:rtemp];
        NSDecimalNumber *payFinalDecimal = (NSDecimalNumber *) [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:payfinal];
        NSDecimalNumber *principalDecimal = (NSDecimalNumber *) [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:principalA];
        for (n = n * 12; n != 0; --n) {
            NSDecimalNumber *realBalanceDecimal = [balDeciminal decimalNumberBySubtracting:principalDecimal];

            NSDecimalNumber *interestDecimal = [balDeciminal decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:rTempDecimal];
            NSDecimalNumber *principalDecimalAmount = [payFinalDecimal decimalNumberBySubtracting:interestDecimal];



        NSString *tempInterest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", interestDecimal];
        [interestLabels addObject:tempInterest];
        NSString *tempPrincipal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", principalDecimalAmount];
        [pricipalLabels addObject:tempPrincipal];
        NSString *tempBalance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", balDeciminal];
        [balanceLabels addObject: tempBalance];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", balanceLabels);
    NSLog(@"%@", pricipalLabels);
    NSLog(@"%@", interestLabels);
```

If NSDecimalNumber doesn't allow me to make these sort of calculations could someone suggest something else that will return a result that is accurate?

Thanks!

EDIT : Double Code

```
double r = interestAmountValue/200;
    //NSLog(@"%f", r);
    double n = yearAmountValue;
    double rPower = pow(1+r, 0.166666666);
    double tophalf = rPower - 1;
    double nPower = (-12 * n);
    double bothalf = pow(rPower, nPower);
    double bothalffinal = 1 - bothalf;
    double tempfinal = tophalf / bothalffinal;
    double payfinal = loanAmountValue * tempfinal;
    double totalPaymentd = payfinal * n * 12;

    double totalInterestd = totalPaymentd - loanAmountValue;

for (n = n * 12; n != 0; --n) {



        double realBalance = balanceAmount - principalA;
        double interest = balanceAmount * rtemp;
        NSLog(@"%f", interest);
        double principalAmount = payfinal - interest;





        balanceAmount -= principalA;
}
```

Comment: Hi What results are you getting and what are your expected results if you give values for variables such as r and loanPaymentValue that would also be helpful

Comment: Also what object type are the balanceLabels ect?

Comment: balanceLabels are MutableArrays

Comment: Could you give the values for, interestAmountValue, yearAmountValue, loanAmountValue and what you are trying to calculate also I assume principalA == principalAmount in your edited code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the problem you were having is that you weren't checking was the loan payed off and you were entering negative numbers meaning the underlying problem is with the spreading of payments.

```
double loanAmountValue = 100000;
double balanceAmount = loanAmountValue;
double n = 30;
double interestAmountValue = 8;
double r = interestAmountValue/1200;
double rtemp = r/(n*12);
double intA = balanceAmount * rtemp;


//NSLog(@"%f", r);
double rPower = pow(1+r, 0.166666666);
double tophalf = rPower - 1;
double nPower = (-12 * n);
double bothalf = pow(rPower, nPower);
double bothalffinal = 1 - bothalf;
double tempfinal = tophalf / bothalffinal;
double payfinal = loanAmountValue * tempfinal;
double principalA = balanceAmount - intA;
double totalPaymentd = payfinal * n * 12;

double totalInterestd = totalPaymentd - loanAmountValue;

for (n = n * 12; n != 0; --n) {



    double realBalance = balanceAmount - principalA;
    double interest = balanceAmount * rtemp;
    NSLog(@"interest: %f", interest);
    NSLog(@"rtemp: %f",rtemp);
    double principalAmount = payfinal - interest;



    // Check for negative balance
    if (balanceAmount < principalAmount) {

        NSLog(@"Balance Amount: %f",balanceAmount);
        NSLog(@"Months Left: %f",n);

        break;
    }

    balanceAmount -= principalAmount;


    NSLog(@"balanceAmount %f",balanceAmount);
}
```

Using your code with the values of n = 30 years, loanAmountValue = 100000, and interestAmountValue = 8%. I had the loan payed off with 63 months left. I assume r = interestAmountValue/1200 instead of 200 to get percentage per month?
Regarding use of NSDecimal number I don't know what impact floating point precision will have on your corrected mortgage calculator, but the problem you were having was not with using double data types it is with the spreading of payments.

Comment: 200 is for Canadian Mortgages where interest is compounded semi annually. So basically what your saying is the math for my loop is wrong regardless of double or not. a mortgage that last 30 years should be paid off in exactly 360 months.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what makes you think that putting a double into an NSDecimalNumber could somehow create extra precision. And it looks to me that in the loop you are always doing the exact same calculation.

double gives about 15 to 16 decimals of precisions. If you are calculating a loan for 30 years, it is very unlikely that you will run into problems due to not having enough precision. I'd suggest that you post your code with double precision numbers and let people have a look at where you went wrong.

Comment: Someone said that NSDecimalNumber is a must for working with currency so I am trying it. This is for amortization schedule. What is happening is the balance is becoming negative before the end of the term. Just a few months into the term and the balance number is already off by a couple dollars when subtracting the principal. I have posted the other code that I was using prior. I appreciate the help thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to be cleaned and checked:
The `for` loop is not producing a change per iteration.
Use the debugger to figure out why. Perhaps the fact that five variables are not being used is a hint.

The following variables are not used:

```
intA
principalA
principal
principalDecimal
realBalanceDecimal
```